# Windows 10 Photos App Won't Work (-2143326208)

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, photos

I've had quite a few problems with my computer lately, but after I installed updates, there was a problem with the Photos app. It's impossible for me to open an image with the app - it will open for a brief second, try to load the image, close, then open an error popup with this: -2143326208 error code.

Opening in another program works fine.

Comment: That's 0x803F7000. Not sure what this means, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest enabling and setting the windows photo viewer as your default photo viewer -- the same one that used to be default on windows 7 / 8.

Change these setting in regedit to enable the windows photo viewer

**Goto:**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open
Add String called MuiVerb with value @photoviewer.dll,-3043
```

[image]

**Then:**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\command
Make sure you have a Default string with this value:
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

[image]

**Then:**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\DropTarget
Add String Clsid with value {FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}
```

[image]

**Then:**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\command
Make sure you have a Default string with this value:
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

[image]

**Lastly:**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\DropTarget
Add String Clsid with value {60fd46de-f830-4894-a628-6fa81bc0190d}
```

[image]

**Now** when you right click on image file --> Open With --> Choose Another App you can choose to set windows photo viewer and set it as the default.

[image]

Comment: OK, did that. Oddly enough, it seems as though someone did already. Thumbnails don't generate though, any way to fix that? EDIT: For some reason the thumbnail generation was turned off in my settings.